# How to authenticate with Dropbox API from a desktop application?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I am trying to develop an application that will be run locally on the user's computer. I want to use the Dropbox API to store and synchronize some app-specific files.

Everywhere throughout the Dropbox documentation it is assumed that the application is a web application. It looks like the only option to authenticate is through OAuth. If the application is run on my own server, then it's not a problem to store the application's *secret* code (which is required for OAuth, as seen in [the example](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.org/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.oauth.DropboxOAuth2Flow)). But in my case, if I run a web server that implements OAuth on the user's computer, I will have to publish the *secret*.

There seems to be another option – running a global server just for the authentication part, then redirecting back to the server running on localhost. But I really dislike this.

So, my question is:
Is there any better way to authenticate with Dropbox API from the user's computer?
Or is it OK to publish the application's *secret*?

Comment: You will always need a step to initially authorize the app for OAuth-2.0 - which may be on a global server, but once authorized, the desktop app only needs to store the refresh-token for the user.  The secret should never be published.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly undesirable to publish one's app secret, so in OAuth 2, including Dropbox's implementation, there is a mechanism for processing the OAuth flow in a client-side app without using the app secret.

Specifically, client-side apps should use the "token" flow (as opposed to the "code" flow), as documented [here under /oauth2/authorize](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation):

> OAuth 2.0 supports two authorization flows:
>
> - The code flow returns a code via the redirect_uri callback which should then be converted into a bearer token using the /oauth2/token call. This is the recommended flow for apps that are running on a server.
> - The token or implicit grant flow returns the bearer token via the redirect_uri callback, rather than requiring your app to make a second call to a server. This is useful for pure client-side apps, such as mobile apps or JavaScript-based apps.

Unfortunately for the case of client-side Python apps, the OAuth flow in the Dropbox Python SDK is currently only built with server-side apps in mind, and so only implements the code flow, and not the token flow. It is open source though, so you can modify it if/as desired, or implement the token flow separately.

Comment: Any pointers on how to implement token flow for a client-side Python app? I tried started a local web server, but the access token is returned in the URL fragment and is thus inaccessible to the server and to my app.

Comment: @Adam It looks like you posted on the forum as well, so I'll follow up there: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Authorisation-flow-for-a-Python-client-console-app/m-p/350261#M20091

Answer (score -2):

As an easier solution, you could publish encoded `secret`  and decode it on the server-side.

It's just for security reason

Comment: (not the downvoter) This will not help because the whole point is to not have any server. And if I do have a server, I can just store the *secret* there.